# How to fade an image in on load silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, image, animation

Can anyone point me to a resource on how to "fade in" an image on load in silverlight? Basically I have a listbox of items that are returned from a web service and some times the images take a little longer to load, so I wanted to fade them in as they download. I read that I might need a storyboard for this effect. Is this the best route or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any alternatives. The StoryBoard is the best route. You could just animate the Opacity of the image from 0 to 100.

Put the Storyboard in the resources for the UserControl () or in the App.xaml.

Then in your OnOpened event (as you mentioned in the comment):

```
protected void OnOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  // params might be incorrect
  this.fadeInStoryBoard.Stop();
  // your image controls will need x:names set
  this.fadeInAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, ((Image)sender).Name);
  this.fadeInStoryBoard.Start();
}
```

The example storyboard is from:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/AgDynAnimations.aspx
and starting the storyboard: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/03/26/target-multiple-objects-properties-with-one-animation-silverlight.aspx

Comment: any idea how to apply this to the image? I know we should play the animation inside the OnOpened Event.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a utility function to perform the task

```
private void FadeIn(UIElement uilelement)
{
    uilelement.Opacity = 0.0;
    uilelement.Visibility = Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    var timeline = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 1.0, Duration =TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0) };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(timeline, uilelement);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(timeline, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
    var sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Children.Add(timeline);
    sb.Begin();
}

function void image1_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FadeIn(sender as Image);
}
```

You should set the Image to Collapsed, or set its initial Opacity to 0.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" 
       Name="image1"  
       Visibility="Collapsed" 
        ImageOpened="image1_ImageOpened" />
```